# Incorrect handling of invalid form in ngrok

Tags: laravel, ngrok

When I submit an invalid form, I display errors to the user without reloading the page, but ngrok simply treats the request as successful. Although the data is not sent or created in the database. Then I see in the console where ngrok is running "POST /form 302".

If the form is valid, then the data is sent and a record is created in the database.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.